# How can I make a Asynchronous task synchronus

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get two types of data from two different websites and binding it to a list but I'm having a problem with the Async, what I want to do is get info from a rss add it to a list , then get info from another website add it to a list then add the two to a bound observable collection.  But the DownloadStringAsync are over running each otherand the app crashes. Can you help me please?

my code is

```
private static ObservableCollection<Top> top= new ObservableCollection<Top>();
    private static ObservableCollection<string> place= new ObservableCollection<string>();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            LoadSiteContent_A(url1);

           LoadSiteContent_B(url2);


        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection, please connect to use this applacation");



        listBox.ItemsSource = top; //trying to bind listbox after web calls
    }





    public void LoadSiteContent_A(string url)
    {

            //create a new WebClient object
            WebClient clientC = new WebClient();


            clientC.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(a_DownloadStringCompleted);
            clientC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));


    }

     public void LoadSiteContent_B(string url)
    {
            //create a new WebClient object
            WebClient clientC = new WebClient();


            clientC.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(b_DownloadStringCompleted);
            clientC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));


    }

     public void a_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
     {
         string testString = "";


         if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
         {
             string str;

             str = (string)e.Result;

             //Various operations and parsing


                     place.Add(testString);

          }


             }


     }
    public void b_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string testMatch = "";


        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            string str;
            // Size the control to fill the form with a margin
            str = (string)e.Result;

               //Various operations and parsing



                top.Add(new Top(testMatch,(place.Count+1)));


            }



    }


public class TopUsers
{
    public string TopUsername { get; set; }
    public int Place { get; set; }

    public TopUsers(string topusername, int place)
    {
        this.TopUsername = topusername;
        this.Place = place;

    }
}


}
```

Comment: If you want it to be synchronous, why not just call LoadSiteContent_B in the a_DownloadStringCompleted()?  That will mimic synchronous activity, but with the benefits of being asynchronous.

Comment: You're doing great with your async implementation. You just need to find a way to synchronously add to the observable collection. Hint: lookup the 'lock' keyword

Comment: Scratch my hint, you're using a static instance and therefore should rethink your design. Adding to your observable collection should be done on the main thread. new Hint: lookup synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an alternate answer (AlexTheo's solution should work).

All this gets a lot easier when they give us (WP Developers) the new Async stuff.

Your code could be written like this:

```
public async MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DoAsyncLoad();
}
private async Task DoAsyncLoad()  // note use of "async" keyword
{
   if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
   {
        await LoadSiteContent_A("");
        await LoadSiteContent_B("");
   }
   else
        MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection, please connect to use this applacation");

   listBox.ItemsSource = top; //trying to bind listbox after web calls
}

public async Task LoadSiteContent_A(string url)
{
     //create a new WebClient object
     WebClient clientC = new WebClient();

     var result = await clientC.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
     // No need for a Lambda or setting up an event

     var testString = result; // result is the string you were waiting for (will be empty of canceled or errored) 
}
public async Task LoadSiteContent_B(string url)
{
     //create a new WebClient object
     WebClient clientC = new WebClient();

     var result = await clientC.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
     // Again, no need for a Lambda or setting up an event (code is simpler as a result)
     top.Add(new Top(testMatch, place.Count + 1));
 }
```

There are more code changes you would have to make (using the Async versions of the Http calls and marking the LoadSiteContent_A/B as async --and setting a return of Task).

BTW, you can actually load the latest Async-CTP3 and release WP code that is written this way. Most people are a little scared of a CTP though.

I wrote a blog post on this that you can check out here -- http://www.jaykimble.net/metro-nuggets-async-is-your-friend.aspx

Comment: Hi DevTheo when I have this code ` private async Task DoAsyncLoad()  // note use of "async" keyword
{
        }`  I get errors saying semi colon expected and am I missing a using directive?

Comment: The key to what I was saying is that you need to install the Async CTP3 (successfully) and then include the AsyncCtpLibrary_Phone.dll (included with the CTP).  I suspect that you haven't done this so the Phone tools/compiler have no idea what "async" and "await" are. I will go ahead and update my code sample to include a little more of your code, so you can see how it looks. I have a blog post over at my blog on Async -- http://www.jaykimble.net/metro-nuggets-async-is-your-friend.aspx (not sure if that will help or not)

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to make them one after the other like that. By "stacking" them one after the other like that you are losing all the advantages of the asynchronous calls in the first place. Not only that, but on a mobile platform like Windows Phone you have to remember that network calls get queued up for efficient use of the antenna. When you make both the calls simultaneously they have a much higher chance of being executed during the same antenna connection which is a "Good Thing".

Next, each of your callbacks are actually updating completely independent collections. `A` is updating the `place` collection and `B` is updating the `top` collection. So it's not a matter of these two stepping on each other in any way.

The only real problem I see here is simply that you're updating the `top` collection which is set as the `listBox.ItemsSource`. You need to marshal updates to bound data back to the UI thread (aka `Dispatcher` thread)so that the controls that are bound to them will be updating on the correct thread.

So the only change you should have to make to any of your code is to marshal the addition of the new item to the `top` collection back to the `Dispatcher` thread in the `B` callback. That would look like this:

```
public void b_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    string testMatch = ""; 

    if(!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null) 
    { 
        string str; 
        // Size the control to fill the form with a margin 
        str = (string)e.Result; 

        //Various operations and parsing 

        Top newTop = new Top(testMatch,(place.Count+1));

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            top.Add(newTop);
        });
    } 
}
```

With this, all your work remains async/concurrent except for the tiny little part where you add the item to the `top` collection.

Comment: The WebClient class already automatically invokes the callback on the UI thread, you don't have to do it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8/

Comment: Mea culpa if that's the case, I'm not a WP expert. I'm used to "pure" .NET where that is not the way WebClient works. If that is the case, then I cannot imagine what the problem is because I see nothing wrong with the code beyond that. I guess we'll need an exception/stacktrace from @M_K.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe that a lamdba will be better than the callback in your case. 
In order to synchronize the downloading you have to call the LoadSiteContent_B in the complete event of LoadSiteContent_A.

```
private static ObservableCollection<Top> top= new ObservableCollection<Top>();
    private static ObservableCollection<string> place= new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private string _url1;
    private string _url2;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage(string url1, string url2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            _url1 = url1;
            _url2 = url2;
            LoadSiteContent_A(url1);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection, please connect to use this applacation");
        listBox.ItemsSource = top; //trying to bind listbox after web calls
    }

    public void LoadSiteContent_A(string url)
    {
            //create a new WebClient object
            WebClient clientC = new WebClient();
            clientC.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => { 
             string testString = "";
             if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
             {
                 string str;
                 str = (string)e.Result;
                 //Various operations and parsing
                place.Add(testString);
                LoadSiteContent_B(_url2);
              }
            };

            clientC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    public void LoadSiteContent_B(string url)
    {
            //create a new WebClient object
            WebClient clientC = new WebClient();
            clientC.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => {/*do whatever you need*/};
            clientC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
    }


public class TopUsers
{
    public string TopUsername { get; set; }
    public int Place { get; set; }

    public TopUsers(string topusername, int place)
    {
        this.TopUsername = topusername;
        this.Place = place;

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with the lambda, there is a much more elegant solution - use a custom Action, where T is the data type.

For example:

```
public void LoadSiteContent_A(string url, Action<string> onCompletion)
{
        //create a new WebClient object
        WebClient clientC = new WebClient();

        clientC.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
        {
             onCompletion(e.Result);
        };
        clientC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}
```

When you are calling this method, you could pass an action like this:

```
LoadSiteContent_a(yourUrlWhatever, data =>
{
   // DO SOMETHING WITH DATA
});
```